# String checking functions in functional JavaScript

Tags: javascript, strings, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

Please review these string checking functions. This is the whole module
which is actually written [here](https://github.com/Arch-Mage/string-is/blob/master/src/index.js). It supports `buffer`, `array`, and
`string` by checking the `char` code.

```
const charCode = chr => typeof chr === 'number' ? chr : chr.charCodeAt(0)

const every = (fn) => (list) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
    if (!fn(list[i])) return false
  return true
}

const compose   = (f, g) => a => f(g(a))
const inBetween = (num, min, max) => num >= min && num <= max

const space        = code => code == 9  || code == 10 || code == 12 ||
                             code == 13 || code == 32
const numeric      = code => inBetween(code, 48, 57)
const lowerAlpha   = code => inBetween(code, 97, 122)
const upperAlpha   = code => inBetween(code, 65, 90)
const alpha        = code => lowerAlpha(code) || upperAlpha(code)
const alphaNumeric = code => numeric(code)    || alpha(code)
const printable    = code => space(code)      || inBetween(code, 32, 127)
```

My thought is is that this style is less readable than the [original](https://github.com/Arch-Mage/string-is/blob/be0a52e2aa16a97cae4d1ee5fea57ecbbceb870e/src/index.js) one. What do you think about its readability? And do these functions satisfy what
said as *functional*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these are rather readable, actually more so than the [original ones](https://github.com/Arch-Mage/string-is/blob/72db229245b0e84b3e04a676b0a94a1dd8de3983/src/index.js). You've condensed the functions considerably!

#### Going pointfree

One further possibility would be to go more "pointfree", which you find a lot of in Haskell, for example. Define `or` in terms of functions (so its arguments can be evaluated lazily), then you can work at a higher level of abstraction:

```js
const or = (f, g) => (...args) => f.apply(f, args) || g.apply(g, args)

const alpha        = or(lowerAlpha, upperAlpha)
const alphaNumeric = or(numeric, alpha)
const printable    = or(space, inBetween(32, 127))
```

And then you can configure `inBetween` to accept the variable parameter separately:

```
const inBetween  = (a, b) => x => a <= x && x <= b

const space      = x => [9, 10, 12, 13, 32].includes(x)
const numeric    = inBetween(48, 57)
const lowerAlpha = inBetween(97, 122)
const upperAlpha = inBetween(65, 90)
```

I find this a bit more readable, since it removes the repetition of the parameter `code`. The resulting code is denser and reads nicely: "alpha means either lowerAlpha or upperAlpha", etc.

But really this comes down to your preferences. As far as

> do these functions satisfy what said as *functional*?

that depends on your definitions/requirements. I'd say they're certainly functional in the sense of avoiding mutability, except for `every`, and in the philosophy of composing together small functions.

#### `every`

A more functional `every` might recurse while fn(x) is truthy and elements remain in the list, something like this:

```
const every = (pred, [head, ...tail]) =>
    pred(head) && (tail.length ? every(pred, tail) : true)
```

but this won't behave nicely in current JS engines. One modification you could do now, though, is to use `for...of` in `every`, so that it also works on Sets, ES7 generators, and other iterables that might not be indexable:

```
const every = pred => list => {
    for (let x of list) {
        if (!pred(x)) return false
    }
    return true
}
```